# change command text programmatically

Tags: codenameone

I want to change the text of the command in title bar programmatically but it is not happening. Why doesn't the command name "aaa" changes to "bbb" in the following code?

```
labourChargeSumCommand = new Command("") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
};
labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("aaa");
getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(labourChargeSumCommand);

cb1.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (cb1.isSelected()) {
        labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("bbb");
        getToolbar().revalidate();
    }
});
```

Update: all my code

```
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    Command labourChargeSumCommand;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        hi.show();

        labourChargeSumCommand = new Command("") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            }
        };
        labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("aaa");
        hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(labourChargeSumCommand);

        Button bb = new Button("bb");
        bb.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (true) {
                labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("bbb");
                System.out.println(labourChargeSumCommand.getCommandName());
                hi.getToolbar().revalidate();
                hi.getToolbar().repaint();
            }
        });
        hi.add(bb);
    }

}
```

Here I have added a btn and kept code inside its action listener, that's all.

Comment: First debug **cb1.isSelected()** returns **true**

Comment: yeahh, it returns true. What I want to do is when I select the checkbox, the command in the title bar should change. It works for setTitle() but not here

Comment: Try to call getToolbar().repaint(); after getToolbar().revalidate();

Comment: no, doesn't work

Comment: use following code for test:          if (true) {
            labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("bbb");
            System.out.println(labourChargeSumCommand.getCommandName());
            getToolbar().revalidate();
            getToolbar().repaint();
        }

Comment: the correct value is printing out but it doesn't change in toolbar

Comment: Search for **labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName** from your code I think you may override the value some where else.

Comment: no nowhere.. I remove all the codes, add a btn and your codes above. it prints out the correct value but command doesn't change.

Comment: What do you mean by command doesn&#39;t change? Can repost your tried part code.

Comment: I mean text name of the command doesn't change

Comment: And I've added all the code for test above. Have a look

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: Try `toolbar.findCommandComponent(command).setText(...)`

Comment: thankyou shai it works...

Answer (score 1):

> change command text programatically

I just comment this code **//hi.show();** add it at the end. Becuase of this 
**revalidate()** not worked, So that **labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("bbb");** text not updated.

```
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    Command labourChargeSumCommand;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        //hi.show();
        labourChargeSumCommand = new Command("") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            }
        };
        labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("aaa");
        hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(labourChargeSumCommand);

        Button bb = new Button("bb");
        bb.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (true) {
                labourChargeSumCommand.setCommandName("bbb");
                System.out.println(labourChargeSumCommand.getCommandName());
                hi.getToolbar().revalidate();
                hi.getToolbar().repaint();
            }
        });
        hi.add(bb);
        hi.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the command name after adding it to the Toolbar doesn't change the text.

What I do is creating a new command and look for the index of the added command, and replace it with the new one.

This is not so efficient nor is it the best way, but it's a hack that works for me.

Let's say we added the command to the right bar and its the last component in the ToolBar container *(You can find it's position through Component Inspector)*:

```
private void switchCommand(Toolbar t, Command cmd) {
    try {
        int pos = t.getComponentCount() - 1;
        Button cmdButton = new Button(cmd.getCommandName());
        cmdButton.setUIID("TitleCommand");
        cmdButton.setCommand(cmd);
        t.replaceAndWait(t.getComponentAt(pos), cmdButton, null);
        t.getComponentForm().revalidate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Then I do this:

```
labourChargeSumCommand = Command.create("aaa", null, evt -> {});
getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(labourChargeSumCommand);

cb1.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (cb1.isSelected()) {

        labourChargeSumCommand = Command.create("bbb", null, evt -> {});
        switchCommand(getToolbar(), labourChargeSumCommand);
    }
});


public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    Command labourChargeSumCommand;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        hi.show();

        labourChargeSumCommand = Command.create("aaa", null, evt -> {});
        hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(labourChargeSumCommand);

        Button bb = new Button("bb");
        bb.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (true) {
                labourChargeSumCommand = Command.create("bbb", null, evt -> {});
                switchCommand(getToolbar(), labourChargeSumCommand);
                System.out.println(labourChargeSumCommand.getCommandName());
            }
        });
        hi.add(bb);
    }

}
```